# Equivalent of set= and getActionCommand in Android Java?

Tags: java, android

I've just started learning Android development and as a little project, I'm building a calculator. The way it works is that when a number button is pressed, the number is appended to the EditText. I don't want to write this code for each of the buttons, because it's tedious and blatantly inefficient but i'm not sure how to go about it.

When I programmed in Java, I got around the problem by setting the ActionCommand of the JButton equal to the number and then making a general

```
textField.append(button.getActionCommand());
```

Is this possible in Android? Is there a better approach?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add tag to every button. In `onClick` method retrieve tag from button and append it to edit box. `OnClickListener` for all number buttons will be the same:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
  String value = v.getTag();
  editText.getText().append(value);
}
```

So you can use 1 instance of `OnClickListener` for all buttons.